# Docker instance of MySQL is not setting root password -- any login without a password is allowed

Tags: mysql, docker, sequelpro

I set up a new computer running macOS 10.14.5 and Docker Desktop community 2.0.0.3 (31259) and I noticed that my MySQL container wasn't being created properly.  This is the command that I had run on my previous computer:

```
docker run --name virtual-mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword -d mysql:5.7.22
```

That worked: it would properly set the root password.  But on the new computer, when I run that command, the root password is NOT set.  I can log in as the root user, but only if I leave the password blank.  Only the root user can create a database.

But more curiously, I can specify ANYTHING as the user, e.g. `asdf` *and successfully log in* (!!!).  When I log in as a non-existent user, I can only view the `information_schema` and I cannot create a database, however -- I get an error: `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'asdf'` -- which suggests that perhaps my client isn't sending the login credentials correctly (I am using Sequel Pro 1.1.2 as my MySQL client).

Can someone explain this strange behavior?

Comment: mysql image doesnt do well with non linux platforms. see for yourself: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.5/en/docker-mysql-getting-started.html

Comment: Docker MySQL works fine on macOS. It certainly sounds like your connection details are getting messed up though - are you using the "Standard" (not "Socket" or "SSH") connection tab, with `127.0.0.1:3306`? I tried exactly your Docker command, also using Sequel Pro 1.1.2, and everything works as expected. Could there be another MySQL instance running on your machine, and you're actually connecting to it? Does `docker logs` show anything?

Comment: You were on to something there -- one of the apps I installed "helpfully" installed a version of MySQL onto the host OS.  I have since removed that (and the mysql-connector-c), but still, I cannot log into the MySQL 5.6 container using a password (yes, this is a standard connection, not via a Socket or SSH connection).

I noticed something else curious: even on my old computer where this was working, I can still log into the containers if I OMIT the password entirely (!).  I can set the password and use it during logins for MySQL 5.7, but 5.6 seems unable to tolerate a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some helpful nudging, I figured out where this was going off the rails.

First problem: one of the apps I installed had installed an instance of MySQL onto the host OS.  I didn't notice it because I had done `which mysql` from an open Terminal window that didn't have its PATH updated.

Second problem: mysqld kept running a process that bound to port 3306.
I didn't notice this until running `lsof -Pnl +M -i4 | grep 'LISTEN'lsof -Pnl +M -i4 | grep 'LISTEN'` revealed it.  I had my suspicions when I could bring up new dockerized instances bound to other ports.

So the solution was to THOROUGHLY delete mysql (and mysqld), then REBOOT to shake any dangling connections. Once I had done that, my dockerized versions ran fine.